# Making a loop for running median

Tags: python, while-loop, numpy-ndarray

For a course I'm doing we are given a timeseries dataset with one array being observations of velocity. The task is to design a while loop that finds the median of an odd-numbered window around a given point, for each observation, and make a new array of the same length with the observations replaced by the median from the window. I cannot use built in functions like np.median and np.sliding_view.

I designed a while loop that looks for the largest and smallest value in the window, and deletes it from the window, and re-evaluates until the smallest value equals the largest value(the median). However, whenever I try to run this code, the np.delete section gives an error "IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 0"

Here's the loop:

```
winlen= 9 #Window length, of some positive odd integer. 


backrange=int(-(winlen-1)/2) #Back end of window
forrange= int((winlen+1)/2) #Front end of window
Vel_Med=np.array([]) 
for pos in range(0, len(Data_Vel)): #Data vel, velocity obsevations, length 6464
    if pos<(winlen-1)/2: #Making shape of window depending on if it's at the edge of the array or not
            forw=forrange+pos
            back = pos
    elif pos> len(Data_Vel)-(winlen)/2:
            forw = pos
            back= backrange+pos
    else:
            forw=forrange+pos
            back=backrange+pos
    i= Data_Vel[back: forw] #make the window
    sml=0
    lrg=1
    while sml != lrg: #While small does not equal large, run this loop    
        sml=np.inf #Reset small and large when the loop runs 
        lrg=-np.inf                        
        indx_list = []
        for num in i:
            if num>lrg:     #Find the largest number in the window, and the index position
                lrg=num   
                pos_lrg= int(np.array(np.where(i==lrg))[0,0])     
                    
            if num <sml: #Find the smallest number in the window, and the index position
                sml=num 
                pos_sml= int(np.array(np.where(i==sml))[0,0])
            
        i=np.delete(i, [pos_lrg, pos_sml]) #Delete the smallest and largest number from the array, re-evaluate
                
    median=sml     #When small=large, median =sml           
    Vel_Med=np.append(Vel_Med,median)
```

Comment: why do you want to do it this way? And not just use sort and get the middle value?

Comment: You don't want to use [`np.median`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.median.html) or [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html)?

Comment: It's an exercise, not for any kind of larger project. It's mainly just to get practice using loops, they prohibited using those functions in this.

Comment: Are you missing a `lrg=num` line?

Comment: Ah yes, let me update that. I must have accidentally deleted it while writing up this post